# The padding-left property do not get honored while conversion to PDF/RTF

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have the XSL-FO like the way below : -

```
<fo:table-cell border="1pt"  number-columns-spanned="1" background-color="yellow" number-rows-spanned="1" display-align="before" relative-align="from-table-column()" role="html:td" font-size="9pt">
<fo:block>
    <fo:block role="html:div" padding="4px">
        <fo:inline role="html:span">
            <fo:inline role="html:span" font-weight="bold" text-decoration="underline">Some Text Here1 </fo:inline>
        </fo:inline>
        <fo:block role="html:div" >
            <fo:block role="html:div" padding-start="40pt" >Some text here 2&lt;$&gt;: <fo:inline role="html:span" >some text here 3</fo:inline>
                <fo:inline role="html:span"> some text here 4</fo:inline>some text here 5<fo:inline role="html:span">some text here 6.</fo:inline>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:block>
</fo:block>
```

The padding-left property is not getting honored while conversion to PDF/RTF.
The html conversion through this XSL-FO is honoring the padding-left property

Can anybody help me with this ? Is there any thing wrong in the wrong in XSL-FO or the conversion is going for a toss ?

Appreciate your help on this ....

Comment: There is no `padding-left` in your sample.  Do you mean `padding-start`?

Comment: yes padding-start